# What is the right answer of number 37?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, american-english

I want to know how to say that..is that correct?

"What is the right answer of number 37?"

I was taking an exam. After that, my teacher said "so the answer is (a)", but I missed to hear what she said. I asked my friend what the answer is then I said "What is the right answer of number 37?"

Is this right? and this story is easy to understand? no wrong grammar? and not strange?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your sentence.You could replace '_number_' with '_question_', to marginally increase clarity and to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

It's very close, and it is grammatical. However, the American English way of asking this question would be,

> What's the right answer **to** number 37?

I'd also argue that the context indicates that you're asking about a question, so there isn't a need to use the word question in your question. It is perfectly acceptable shorthand to use "number" to refer to a question on a numbered exam.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is one which a native English speaker could use informally, but if you want to be completely correct, you should probably say "question number 37" (or just "question 37").  Perhaps you should also prefer "answer to" over "answer of".